# Push Firebase Value to Dropdown

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using **Vuetify** to create my dropdown. I can select a value, push it to the firebase database, but refresh of the page I cannot populate the dropdown.

Here is the template:

```
<template>
        <v-select
              v-bind:items="itemsPhone"
              v-model="telephoneType1"
              id="telephone-pro-type-1"
              label="Select"
              single-line
              bottom
         > </v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data () {
     return {
       telephoneType1:'',
       itemsPhone: [
             { text: 'Mobile' },
             { text: 'Emergency' },
             { text: 'Weekend' }
           ],
     }
</script>
```

Here is the code used to populate the other fields, but i cannot populate the dropdown.

```
mounted(){
  var that = this;
  var query = db.ref('Clients/'+ clientName +'/'); // shortened 

  query.once('value')
         .then((snapshot) => {

                that.emailPro = snapshot.child('emailPro').val();
                that.telephoneType1 = snapshot.child('telephoneType1').val();
         });


}
```

I have tried many ways, including vanilla javascript to push the value to the dropdown by targeting the exact class or id...but it doesn't populate.

Comment: where are you setting `itemsPhone`?

Comment: Hi Frank! I just added the code. I'm still stuck. Let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not Frank :), You want the dropdown to be set to a value you got from firebase?

Comment: lol how can I miss that..! Yes exactly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `label` attribute is used to set a default value. Currently you are setting it to 'Select', instead set `telephoneType1 : 'Select`

And set the label to that attribute:

```
<v-select
         v-bind:items="itemsPhone"
         v-model="telephoneType1"
         id="telephone-pro-type-1"
         :label="telephoneType1"
         single-line
         bottom
> </v-select>
```

On another issue, your code is overly verbose, since you are using fat arrow function (=>) there is no need for setting `that=this`, fat arrow functions maintain the context of `this` for you, so you can change the code:

```
mounted(){  
  var query = db.ref('Clients/'+ clientName +'/'); // shortened 

  query.once('value')
         .then((snapshot) => {

                this.emailPro = snapshot.child('emailPro').val();
                this.telephoneType1 = snapshot.child('telephoneType1').val();
         });


}
```

Comment: @Fatman..on refresh and changing the value..I got an error: "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "label". Expected String, got Object."

Comment: The error says it, it expects a string but you got an object from firebase. console.log the object so you can explore it's structure, and then set the appropriate property and not the entire object

Comment: Thanks again! IF anyone wondering, :label="telephoneType1.text" worked after logging the object.